# vb.net change value of a cell in a databound datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview that has been populated from a datatable using the datasource property. I need to change the value of a cell without affecting the database. So far I could only find that I have to first change the databound item but no information about how to do that. Besides, I don't want to change the databound item.

The reason for wanting to do this is that I have a list of records with a start and end time and there is a computed field that gives the difference in seconds. I need to change the value of the computed field and change the height of the row accordingly, that is, the height of each row is proportional to the duration it represents. Changes are done from a text box which increments quickly if the "increase" button is kept down and therefore I cannot change the database with each increment. Rather I would change the value in the table frequently and update the database once the increments stops.

I have tried updating the datagridview directly using this code:

```
dgvTasks.Rows(SelectedRowIndex).Cells(5).Value = DateAdd(DateInterval.Minute, DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, CDate("00:00:00"), CDate(txtDuration.Text & ":00")), dgvTasks.Rows(SelectedRowIndex).Cells(4).Value)
```

But receive the error:

> System.Data.ReadOnlyException: Column 'Column1' is read only.

I also tried updating the datatable, and allowing the calculated column to update:

```
dtblTasks.Rows(SelectedRowIndex)(5) = DateAdd(DateInterval.Minute, DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, CDate("00:00:00"), CDate(txtDuration.Text & ":00")), dtblTasks.Rows(SelectedRowIndex)(4)) 
dgvTasks.DataSource = dtblTasks
```

But the calculated value doesn't change.

I am also providing an additional calculated value (in the SQL) where I find the difference in minutes and the append a string literal  to that:

```
( CAST ( DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Tasks.TaskStart, Tasks.TaskEnd) AS NVARCHAR(10) ) + ' mins') AS TaskDurationString
```

Is there a way to detach the grid from the datasource but still keep the data visible in the datagrid and manipulate it (without affecting the databound object)? Or perhaps some other approach to this problem?

Comment: What exact sort of change do you want to make? It is quite easy to apply transformations to the displayed values in a datagridview without altering the underlying datasource. There is no way to 'disconnect' a datasource and keep the data showing in the grid. You can however simple us an unbound grid and copy the values from the datatable in code. Finally however, the simplest approach would be to update the datatable - Why can't you do that? You don't have to save the changes to the datatable back to the database.

Comment: This is the error I am getting when I try to alter the contents of a cell using the following command:    DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(0).Value = "test"   linkdl.dropbox.com/u/60390967/LANThrax/error.jpg    
I just realized that if I try to change the content of a cell that is attached to one a single field it works. If, however, I try to change a cell whose value is a result of a combination of other fields, such "(FirstName + LastName)", it gives me that error.

Comment: Well no, that won't work - computed columns in DataTables are readonly and there is no way around that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810291.aspx but why do you need the computed column, and why do you want to change its value? There are plenty of possible paths to solve your problem but it still isn't clear exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I have a list of records with a start and end time and the computed field is the difference in seconds. I need to change the value of the computed field and change the height of the row accordingly, that is, the height of each row is proportional to the duration it represents. Changes are done from a text box which increments quickly if the "increase" button is kept down and therefore I cannot change the database with each increment. Rather I would change the value in the table frequently and update the database once the increments stops. I will try updating the end time instead.

Comment: Updating the endtime would be the way to go - then your computed column will update too. When you say "therefore I cannot change the database with each increment" do you mean this is why you don't update the datatable directly? There is no reason why you should hit the database unless you want to. If you have some events automatically triggering trips to the database I'd suggest rethinking that design.

Comment: No, what I meant is that I did not want to update the database and force the datatable to reload the correct data from the database. That would have worked if there was a single increment.         Now I managed to change the End time but the computed field is not updating to reflect the change. How do I force it to recompute? I tried using `DataGridView1.Refresh` but that didn't work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18807/discussion-between-david-hall-and-osprey)

Comment: I just added a lot of the detail from our chat into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating the calculated column in the `DataTable` should work -  I've just tried it, and both when I edit one of the values that are part of the calculated value, and when I change the value in code, that column is recalculated and the grid UI updates.

One thing to check is that you are calculating the value correctly. You should be using the `DataTable~ column [`Expression` property][1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Something like this:

```
dt.Columns["FullName"].Expression = "FirstName + LastName";
```

---

Since it appears that you don't actually need to bind any of these values to the `DataTable` or persist them to the database, one possible solution is to do all of this in an unbound `DataGridView` calculation column.

To do that add a column using the designer, then in the cell validating event have something like this:

```
void dataGridView1_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["TargetColumn"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["FirstName"].Value.ToString() + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["LastName"].Value.ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Height = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["LastName"].Value.ToString().Length + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["FullName"].Value.ToString().Length;
}
```

Comment: I just remembered that you asked for vb.net - just post a comment here and I'll happily update my code to that from c#

Comment: Thanks, David. I tried the unbound datagridview column approach. The CellValidate event did not update the cell while the other columns where being changed so I set the calculated cell to update in the same method as that updates the others. Now I just need to find a way to set the unbound column not to be the left most.

Comment: DisplayIndex should do this for you - not at a computer with a datagridview project to test on though.